# Minutes formatting issue in Query date time picker

Tags: jquery, date, jquery-plugins, datetimepicker, datetime-format

I am new to jQuery but I have been programming for more than two years in C#. I am developing a MVC project, there I have implemented a jQuery date time picker that would be used for get the user input for start date. I thought that I created the proper date time format for that. Because it shows what I want in most PCs Ex: - ‘12/05/2015 12:04’. But in some PCs it’s getting screwed when the value of minutes is less than 10. It doesn’t show the zero in front of the last digit of the minutes. Like this: - ‘12/05/2015 12:4’.

•   Here is my HTML code for Date Time Picker:

```
{<input class="col-sm-6 col-xs-12" type="text" id="txtStart" value = '@(Model.Appointment.StartTime == null ? null : Model.Appointment.StartTime.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm"))' disabled="disabled"  />}
```

•   Here is my script for Date Time Picker:

```
<script type="text/javascript">    
$('#txtStart').datetimepicker({ step: 10, format: 'd/m/Y H:i' });

…
…
…
</script>
```

•   Here is the link for the ‘Date Time Picker’ resource that I am using :

http://www.jqueryscript.net/time-clock/Clean-jQuery-Date-Time-Picker-Plugin-datetimepicker.html

Can you please advise me on this?

Thanks for helping, Kushan Randima.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added following method to set the current Date and Time to the DateTimePicker. It helped me to solve the issue. I have done some tricks to get the exact same format that I need.

```
//Set Current Date & Time to "txtStart"     
        var currentdate = new Date();            
        var datetime = ("0" + currentdate.getDate()).slice(-2) + "/"
                    + ("0" + (currentdate.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2) + "/"
                    + currentdate.getFullYear() + " "
        + ("0" + currentdate.getHours()).slice(-2) + ":"
        + ("0" + currentdate.getMinutes()).slice(-2);
```

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the seconds format for date:

```
<script type="text/javascript">    
$('#txtStart').datetimepicker({ step: 10, format: 'd/m/Y H:i:s' });
```

Comment: I will try this. I may take few hours to let you know the results. Because the trouble making machine is in UK. I am in Sri Lanka. I have to wait til they appear online :-) Thanks

Comment: I'm sorry, it did not work for me. I found a way of fixing that. Please see my answer. I appreciate your effort all the time. Thanks